# How can I convert a timestamp (nanoseconds from 0) into Y:D:H:M:S:m:n?

Tags: algorithm, time, datetime-conversion

I have a timestamp (64-bit integer) that represents the number of nanoseconds from 0 (imagine it representing how long a stopwatch has been running). To test this, I am using `31,740,770,222,000,008`, which is [1 year, 2 days, 3 hours, 4 minutes, 5 seconds, 6 milliseconds, and 7 nanoseconds in nanoseconds](http://wolfr.am/1bLIFE8), and I want to convert this integer back into years, days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, and nanoseconds in the format `Y:D:H:M:S:m:n`, so I expect to see `1:2:3:4:5:6:7`. I also want to be able to pick and choose which resolutions I want, so if the stopwatch is only going to measure times under an hour, I could display it as `M:S:m`, and expect  `4:5:6` from this.

Below is the algorithm I was using, but it isn't working at all (it returns `1:31970222000008:3170222000008:50222000008:222000008:8:8`). **Does anyone know a quick and reliable way to do this?** I want it to perform all calculations in under half a millisecond, so the stopwatch can display the current number of milliseconds.

```
public static final byte
    YEAR        = 0b0100_0000,
    DAY         = 0b0010_0000,
    HOUR        = 0b0001_0000,
    MINUTE      = 0b0000_1000,
    SECOND      = 0b0000_0100,
    MILLISECOND = 0b0000_0010,
    NANOSECOND  = 0b0000_0001,

    RES_DEFAULT = (byte)(MINUTE | SECOND | MILLISECOND);

private static final double
    YEAR_IN_DAYS = 365.24219,
    DAY_IN_HOURS = 24,
    HOUR_IN_MINUTES = 60,
    MINUTE_IN_SECONDS = 60,
    SECOND_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000,

    MILLISECOND_IN_NANOSECONDS = 1_000_000,
    SECOND_IN_NANOSECONDS = SECOND_IN_MILLISECONDS * MILLISECOND_IN_NANOSECONDS,
    MINUTE_IN_NANOSECONDS = MINUTE_IN_SECONDS * SECOND_IN_NANOSECONDS,
    HOUR_IN_NANOSECONDS = HOUR_IN_MINUTES * MINUTE_IN_NANOSECONDS,
    DAY_IN_NANOSECONDS = DAY_IN_HOURS * HOUR_IN_NANOSECONDS,
    YEAR_IN_NANOSECONDS = YEAR_IN_DAYS * DAY_IN_NANOSECONDS;

/**
 * Converts the given number of nanoseconds from timer 0 to a String in the format
 * {@code YYY:DDD:HH:MM:SS:mmmm}
 * where all values have leading zeroes. You can choose which values are used with the resFlags, which can be combined bitwise.
 * @param timeStamp the number of <B>nano</B>seconds away from timer 0
 * @param resFlags the flags representing which levels of resolution to return
 * @return the requested timestamp as a String
 */
public static String toString(long timeStamp, byte resFlags)
{
    return ""+
        ((resFlags & YEAR) != 0
            ? (long)(timeStamp / YEAR_IN_NANOSECONDS)
                + ((resFlags & ~YEAR) != 0
                    ? ":"
                    : "")
            : "")
        + ((resFlags & DAY) != 0
            ? (long)(timeStamp % DAY_IN_NANOSECONDS)
                + ((resFlags & ~(YEAR | DAY)) != 0
                    ? ":"
                    : "")
            : "")
        + ((resFlags & HOUR) != 0
            ? (long)(timeStamp % HOUR_IN_NANOSECONDS)
                + ((resFlags & ~(YEAR | DAY | HOUR)) != 0
                    ? ":"
                    : "")
            : "")
        + ((resFlags & MINUTE) != 0
            ? (long)(timeStamp % MINUTE_IN_NANOSECONDS)
                + ((resFlags & ~(YEAR | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE)) != 0
                    ? ":"
                    : "")
            : "")
        + ((resFlags & SECOND) != 0
            ? (long)(timeStamp % SECOND_IN_NANOSECONDS)
                + ((resFlags & (MILLISECOND | NANOSECOND)) != 0
                    ? ":"
                    : "")
            : "")
        + ((resFlags & MILLISECOND) != 0
            ? (long)(timeStamp % MILLISECOND_IN_NANOSECONDS)
                + ((resFlags & NANOSECOND) != 0
                    ? ":"
                    : "")
            : "")
        + ((resFlags & NANOSECOND) != 0
            ? (long)(timeStamp % 1_000_000)
            : "")
        ;
}
```

Comment: Your test number is incorrect. If it contains 6 milliseconds and 7 nanoseconds, the last digits must be 006,000,007.

Comment: @interjay did you take into account the `365.24219`-day year?

Comment: Ah, I thought you'd use 365 days per year. Even wolfram alpha which you linked uses 365 days.

Comment: @interjay fixed the link!

Comment: @Supuhstar Your value of `365.24219` days/year is only precise to about 864ms - If you really care about nano-second resolution, you'll need a more precise days/year value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each unit past the year, you need to subtract off the portion "consumed" by the previous unit. Then divide (not mod) by the next unit. Something like this, for example:

```
years = timeStamp / YEAR_IN_NANOSECONDS;
timeStamp -= years * YEAR_IN_NANOSECONDS;
days = timeStamp / DAY_IN_NANOSECONDS;
timeStamp -= days * DAY_IN_NANOSECONDS;
// hours next, etc...
```

For days you could also do:

```
days = (timeStamp % YEAR_IN_NANOSECONDS) / DAY_IN_NANOSECONDS;
```

**But**, for each new increment it will get more complicated. The first way generally seems cleaner to me.

You might want to break up that long return statement to facilitate. Get the numbers you want, then build the string after you have them all.